# python convert object into json for mongodb

Tags: python, pymongo

Folks,
  I have the following Class:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name, bd, phone, address):
        self.name = name
        self.bd = bd
        self.phone = phone
        self.address = address


myUser = User(name, bd, phone, address)
```

Now I need to store `myUser` as an object in MongoDB.  Should I use jsondumps for this?  Whats the proper way of converting this object for pymongo?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using an ORM is a good approach in general, depending on the complexity of your system, it might be simpler to do everything "manually".

In your case, it can be simply done as:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name, bd, phone, address):
        self.name = name
        self.bd = bd
        self.phone = phone
        self.address = address

    def to_document(self):
        return dict(
            name = self.name,
            bd = self.bd,
            phone = self.phone,
            address = self.address,
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_document(cls, doc):
        return cls(
            name = doc['name'],
            bd = doc['bd'],
            phone = doc['phone'],
            address = doc['address'],
        )
```

You can also use the "shortcut" versions ...

```
def to_document(self):
    return self.__dict__
@classmethod
def from_document(cls, doc):
    return cls(**doc)
```

... though IMO explicit is better than implicit, and you'd pretty much have to switch to the "full manual version" as things get more complex (e.g. you might need to call one of the field's `to_document` if it's an object).

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

1. Store the user data as a dictionary and then dump in into json. It is doable, but I don't recommend it.
2. Use ORM (Object Relation Mapper) which bascially maps an object (such as user) into a table in the database. The defacto ORM for Python is SQLAlchemy. However, since you mention MongoDB I suggest take a look at [mongokit](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit).